# Problem installing mpi4py on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, mpi

I have mpich2 installed and python 2.7 on Ubuntu 11.04.
I configured without any extra arguments.
When I go to build mpi4py from source, I get this error:

```
$ python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
MPI C compiler:    /usr/bin/mpicc
MPI C++ compiler:  /usr/bin/mpicxx
MPI linker:        /usr/bin/mpicc
checking for MPI compile and link ...
/usr/bin/mpicc -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict prototypes -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
/usr/bin/mpicc _configtest.o -o _configtest
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcr
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
failure.
removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
error: Cannot compile/link MPI programs. Check your configuration!!!
```

Any ideas as to what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are missing [libcr-dev](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+package/libcr-dev).

```
sudo apt-get install libcr-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Another package to try is lam4-dev